# Minecraft lan world on computers

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

Basically me and my brother want to play Minecraft together using a lan world. I just wanted to know if a lan world between two computers sitting in the same room would take a lot of data in an hour. We are both connected to the same WiFi

Answer (score 2):

You will be connected through your network, not the internet.  This will not use internet data.

Answer (score -1):

You need to have a wired connection to the other computer, being on the same network will not work, it basically sends the signal to your router then to your brother's computers instead of directly from your computer to their's. Just get Hamachi, make a server, add your brother to it, Win + R, run [cmd], ipconfig, find your IPv4 Address then start a lan server, **IPv4 Address** **: Lan Address you got from MC**, give that to your brother for Direct Connect and boom, ya got a "lan" world.

Comment: Will this use data

Comment: In your own words: "it basically sends the signal to your router then to your brother's computers".  You never say internet, he is wanting to avoid internet data which an open to LAN world will not use.  LAN stands for **local** area connection.  Your answer adds unneeded complication.

Comment: Explaining things so people won't get confused is not an, in your own works. an "unneeded complication".

Answer (score -1):

No it will not use any data and you can use it with no broadband just a wifi conection